# Bash regex - how to lazily parse a list from HTML file

Tags: regex, bash

I have `changes.html` file and want to parse it in a bash script to get the most recent (topmost) changes list:

```
    . . .
<h1>        Changes        </h1>
<h2>
  <a href="3/changes">#3</a>
</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Recent Text line 1</li>
  <li>Recent Text line 2</li>
</ol>
<h2>
  <a href="2/changes">#2</a>
</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Text line 1</li>
  <li>Text line 2</li>
  <li>Text line 3</li>
</ol>
<h2>
  <a href="1/changes">#1</a>
</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Text line 1</li>
  <li>Text line 2</li>
</ol>
. . .
```

Expected output:

```
Recent Text line 1
Recent Text line 2
```

How can I do this in a bash script?

I've been trying bash regexp, but I'm definitely doing something wrong

```
changes_regex='(<ol><li>.*</li></ol>)?'
changes_list=$(< ~/Documents/outfile.html)

if [[ $changes_list =~ $changes_regex ]]; then
  echo 'match'
  n=${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
  while [[ $i -lt $n ]]; do
      echo "  capture[$i]: ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
      let i++
  done
else
  echo 'no match'
fi
```

The above script returns only:

```
match
  capture[]:
  capture[1]:
```

If I remove brackets in regexp (`changes_regex='<ol><li>.*</li></ol>'`), I get greedy match.

How to correctly build regular expression to lazily get only the first list contents?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. Use syntax aware tools. Provide the complete HTML file with proper syntax

Comment: [Parsing HTML or XML via RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/952747).. I'm not sure it's a good idea. Use a xpath utility.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll take a look at such tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/<ol>/,/<\/ol>/p; /<\/ol>/q' changes.html | sed -r 's/<li>(.*)<\/li>/\1/g;s/<.*//g'
```

Output (6th, 7th line):

```
  Recent Text line 1
  Recent Text line 2
```

I've understood you correctly?

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! I'll use it as a template. However, I'll probably check out other tools not to use regex for parsing html as suggested

Answer (score 1):

Using xmllint and XPath to parse the html

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//h2[a[@href="3/changes"]]/following-sibling::ol[1]/li' first.html | sed -re 's/<li>([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)<\/li>/\1\n/g'
Recent Text line 1
Recent Text line 2
```